# Why is this RSpec test failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm in the process of learning Ruby on Rails, so treat me like a total neophyte, because I am.

I've got a User model with some associated RSpec tests, and the following test fails:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do

    it 'should require a password' do
        User.new({:email => 'valid_email@example.com', :password => '', :password_confirmation => ''}).should_not be_valid
    end

end
```

The relevant part of the `User` model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    validates :password, :presence => true,
                         :confirmation => true,
                         :length => { :minimum => 6 }
    ...
end
```

Here's the catch: if I run `User.new(...).valid?` from a Rails console using the arguments above, it returns false as expected and shows the correct errors (password is blank).

I was using spork/autotest and I restarted both to no avail, but this test also fails even running it directly with `rspec`. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I tried a few more things with the test. This fails:

```
        u = User.new({:email => 'valid_email@example.com', :password => '', :password_confirmation => ''})
        u.should_not be_valid
```

So does this:

```
        u = User.new({:email => 'valid_email@example.com', :password => '', :password_confirmation => ''})
        u.valid?
        u.errors.should_not be_empty
```

This passes, confirming that `:password` is indeed blank:

```
        u = User.new({:email => 'valid_email@example.com', :password => '', :password_confirmation => ''})
        u.password.should == ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's actually spork that is causing the problem. You can turn caching off, so that it won't need restarting every time :

http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/05/09/spork-testing-tip-caching-classes

I think this is what happens :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :020 > u = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, email: ...
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :021 > u.errors
 => {} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :022 > u.save
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > u.errors
 => {:email=>["can't be blank", "can't be blank"], ...}
```

In short, if you change new to create, it will work :) I think that this happens because the matcher be_valid checks on the model validation errors. There can be a deeper explanation, but i think that if you use create instead of new, it will work.

EDIT : I have a be_valid_verbose version that might help. Just create a 'be_valid_verbose.rb' file in your rspec/custom_matchers folder, and inside it write :

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_valid_verbose do
  match do |model|
    model.valid?
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |model|
    "#{model.class} expected to be valid but had errors:n #{model.errors.full_messages.join("n ")}"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |model|
    "#{model.class} expected to have errors, but it did not"
  end

  description do
    "be valid"
  end
end
```

Now check against be_valid_verbose instead of be_valid. It will hopefully present you with some more information on what is happening in your case.

Comment: Interesting distinction, but changing new to create didn't do anything. :(

Comment: hmm, i was actually worried that be_valid calls valid? internally, which runs through the validation errors, seems to be the case. That's weird. It should probably be working with new as well. Maybe should_not cannot evaluate the whole expression properly ? How about passing the result of User.new to a variable and check that ? Also, though it shouldn't play any role, try losing the {} as well. I can't see of anything else that could cause your test to fail :/

Comment: Yes, other tests work with new, so apparently it _ought_ to work. They also work with an all-one-line approach, too...and changing it to assign to a variable in this case made no difference. Thanks for the effort, though!

Comment: Not sure I'm doing this right, but when I add the file to the only custom_matchers directory I could find (rspec-expectations-2.5.0/features/custom_matchers in my case, using rvm) and adjust the test, I get an error during the test that suggests it didn't find your newly-defined be_valid_verbose: 

    User password validations should require a password
        Failure/Error: u.should_not be_valid_verbose
        NoMethodError:
        undefined method `valid_verbose?' for #<User:0x000000051c7280>
        # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: I messed around with it the poor man's way and tried a few things within the test itself. `valid?` returns true, user.password == '', and user.errors is empty after calling `valid?`. So I don't think the problem is with `should_not be_valid`, as it apparently is telling the truth based on what `valid?` itself returns.

Comment: So never mind all this - see my answer. Sorry for wasting your time. :\

Answer (score 0):

As I feared, the answer was stupidity. This was a spork problem. I thought I had killed the existing process and was running rspec independently, but I later found the spork process still running in a different shell, and rspec had been connecting to it all along. Restarting spork (or killing it entirely) and re-running the tests fixed the problem.

I found this particularly deceptive in that rspec continually updated the test output to reflect the fact that it was aware of my test changes, so it appeared to me that it was running against up-to-date code. Now I'm left to wonder what the real utility of spork is, since apparently I can't trust that it's actually running the right tests correctly.

Comment: and i actually thought of that, but i rejected it because you said you restarted spork :D In any case, turn caching off : http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/05/09/spork-testing-tip-caching-classes/

Comment: Never trust the newbie! :P Thanks, I'll give that caching setting a shot and see if it helps over time. Care to put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Don't worry, i understand, i've done the same :D Sure, i'm putting that in my answer below.